# The name '' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use/build an API to pull SharePoint calendars. I found code in GitHub to get me started. When I start trying to use the found code I get the error The name 'myUT.SiteUrl' does not exist in the current context". I've looked many other problems in stackoverflow but I can't seem to find a solution.

```cs
using SpRestUtility;

namespace SP_REST_UTILITY
{


    class Class1
    {
        SpRestUtilities myUT = new SpRestUtilities();

        myUT.SiteUrl = "https://yoursharepoint.com/yoursite";
        myUT.Credentials = private new NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

        SpList listA = myUT.Get_SpList_By_Title("LISTNAME");
    }
}


//  Found code snip

namespace SpRestUtility
{
    public class SpRestUtilities
    {
        #region Properties
        private string _siteUrl;
        public string SiteUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return _siteUrl;
            }
            set
            {
                // Fix given SiteUrl
                _siteUrl = (!value.EndsWith("/")) ? value += "/" : value;
            }
        }
        public NetworkCredential Credentials { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Name spaces are different you should set same name spaces or add second name space as import to main name space.

Comment: I've tried changing the namespace to match but that doesn't help.

Comment: @joe try second approach

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted and then deleted it. But here is the answer.

```
namespace SpRestUtility
```

{

```
class Class1
{
    SpRestUtilities myUT = new SpRestUtilities();

    Class1() {

        myUT.SiteUrl = "https://yoursharepoint.com/yoursite";
        myUT.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

    SpList listA = myUT.Get_SpList_By_Title("LISTNAME");
}
}
```

}